# Is every Tichonov space necessarily homeomorphic to a subset of a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

My textbook says "*A Tichonov space is homeomorphic to a subset of a compact Hausdorff space.*"

**Doesn't the subset also have to be compact Hausdorff?**

Motivation:- For the subset of the compact Hausdorff space to be homeomorphic to a Tichonov space, it will have to be regular and normal. We know that any compact Hausdorff space is both normal and regular. *Is this necessarily true for every subset also?*

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the subset need not be compact Hausdorff. For a very simple example, note that the Tikhonov space $(0,1)$ is a non-compact subspace of the compact Hausdorff space $[0,1]$.

A subspace of a compact Hausdorff space is compact iff it is closed, so in general you can find **lots** of non-compact subspaces of a compact Hausdorff space. It is also entirely possible to find non-normal subspaces of compact Hausdorff spaces. For example, let $X=\omega_1+1$ with the order topology, and let $Y=\omega+1$ with the order topology. Both spaces are compact and Hausdorff, so their product is as well. But $(X\times Y)\setminus\{\langle\omega_1,\omega\rangle\}$ is not normal: the closed sets $\omega_1\times\{\omega\}$ and $\{\omega_1\}\times\omega$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. For that matter $(X\times X)\setminus\{\langle\omega_1,\omega_1\rangle\}$ is another example: the closed sets $\omega_1\times\{\omega_1\}$ and $\{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle:\alpha\in\omega_1\}$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. It is akin to saying every regular normal $T_{1}$ space need not be compact Hausdorff, although the converse is true.

Comment: @Ayush: Somewhat akin, but there’s a better way to think about it. Hausdorffness is a hereditary property: if $X$ has it, so does every subspace of $X$. Regularity is also a hereditary property. But compactness and normality are not hereditary.

Comment: Can I say the subset of the compact hausdorff space has to be regular normal and $T_{1}$?

Comment: @Ayush: Regular, and $T_1$, yes, because those properties are hereditary, but not normal; normality is not hereditary, and I gave a couple of examples of **non**-normal subspaces of compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: You say normality is not hereditary. Could you kindly point out the flaw in the following argument: Let $X^*$ be a subspace of normal space $X$. Assume $X^*$ contains two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$. This implies that there are two closed sets $A'$ and $B'$ in $X$ such that  $A'\cap X^*=A$ and $B'\cap X^*=B$. Correspondingly, there are disjoint open sets $U'$ and $V'$ containing $A'$ and $B'$ in $X$, and $U'\cap X^*$ and $V'\cap X^*$ will be the corresponding disjoint open sets in $X^*$ containing $A$ and $B$.

Comment: A very similar argument for regularity being hereditary is made [here](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Regularity_is_hereditary). I personally thought that if $A$ is closed in $X^*$, then it is NOT necessary that there is a closed set $A'$ in $X$ such that $A'\cap X^*=A$. But that seems to be the argument in the link. Thanks!

Comment: @Ayush: The flaw in the argument is that $A'$ and $B'$ need not be disjoint in $X$. In my examples they cannot be: in both examples the point that I removed from the compact product to get the non-normal subspace is a limit point in the big space of the two sets that are closed in the subspace and not capable of being separated by disjoint open sets in the subspace.

Comment: @Ayush: If $A$ is closed in $X^*$, then $X^*\setminus A$ is open in $X^*$, so there is an open $U$ in $X$ such that $U\cap X^*=X^*\setminus A$. But then $A'=X\setminus U$ is a closed set in $X$ such that $A'\cap X^*=A$. // The argument works for regularity because $x\notin A'$; it fails for normality because it’s possible that $A'\cap B'\ne\varnothing$. (And the proof at that link is excessively clumsy.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian! As for my argument about there not necessarily being a closed set $A'\in X$ corresponding to $A\in X^*$, I realised it's faulty because $A'=A\cup \text{ all the limit points of A in } X\setminus X^*$

Comment: @Ayush: You’re welcome!

Comment: sorry I was going through the comments on loop, and something struck me which now seems obvious, but wasn't so an hour back. Is a Tikhonov space homeomorphic to EVERY subset of $[0,1]$? Terribly sorry if this is already implied somehow in your comments.

Comment: @Ayush: Every subspace of $[0,1]$ **is** a Tikhonov space. Every subspace of any Tikhonov space is Tikhonov. And every Tikhonov space is a subspace of some product of copies of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

No. A trivial counterexample: the open interval $(0,1)$ is Tychonoff (since it is a metric space), and it does embed into a compact Hausdorff spaces - e.g., $[0,1]$ - but regardless of the compact Hausdorff space chosen, and regardless of the embedding chosen, the image of the embedding will not be compact, because it is (by definition of "embedding") homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, and it isn't compact.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have asked two different questions. Are you saying the subset does not have to be compact Hausdorff?

Comment: That's right, the image of the embedding need not be *compact*, since the original space itself need not be compact (of course it must be Hausdorff, as Hausdorff-ness is inherited by subsets).